# is there a way to find the deep details about the motherboard of a laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard

I wanted to replace the damaged motherboard of my laptop, I also want to upgrade the CPU. Unfortunately, it has onboard CPU so I need to make sure that the motherboard with a higher CPU I'm about to replace is completely compatible specifically to the ports, size, etc. to make sure it will fit on the case of the laptop and all the ports and accessories will be connected.

To completely determine, I need to check the specifications of the motherboard, is there a way to do that?

> The exact model of the laptop is: 
>   [HP Pavilion x360 - 13-s120nr (ENERGY STAR)](https://support.hp.com/lamerica_nsc_carib-en/product/hp-pavilion-13-s100-x360-convertible-pc/8499316/model/8961334/product-info?sku=M1X01UA#ABA&serialnumber=8CG5390K4G)
>
> I am planning to use this motherboard:
>   [X360 13T-S100 13-S SERIES I5-6200U MOTHERBOARD 827823-001 828607-001](https://www.ebay.ph/itm/332547781818?ViewItem=&item=332547781818)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the **Service Guide Manual** after all.

This question is similar to this [HP Forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/HP-Pavilion-13-s120nr-compatible-Motherboard-with-CPU-of/m-p/7514294#M561250). The **Part Number** or **Spare Part Number** of hardware should be followed when upgrading or replacing any parts of a laptop. To determine which model is compatible, the **Service Guide Manual** is the key. Usually, this service guide manual is a **hard-copy** that is included in the package when you purchase a laptop, if not you can download a **PDF copy** of it on the **official page** of the product. You can then find a list of hardware with the spare part number on it which is **surely compatible** and **tested by the company**.

In this case, the laptop is [HP Pavilion x360 - 13-s120nr (ENERGY STAR)](https://support.hp.com/lamerica_nsc_carib-en/product/hp-pavilion-13-s100-x360-convertible-pc/8499316/model/8961334/manuals?sku=M1X01UA#ABA&serialnumber=8CG5390K4G), in the **[Manuals](https://support.hp.com/lamerica_nsc_carib-en/product/hp-pavilion-13-s100-x360-convertible-pc/8499316/model/8961334/manuals?sku=M1X01UA#ABA&serialnumber=8CG5390K4G)** you can **[download](https://go.redirectingat.com/?id=92X1584492&xcust=tomshardware_7284516629806174000&xs=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fh10032.www1.hp.com%2Fctg%2FManual%2Fc04825536&sref=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.tomshardware.com%2Fthreads%2Fhp-pavilion-13-s120nr-compatible-motherboard-with-cpu-of-core-i5.3582677%2F%23post-21638342)** a **PDF soft-copy** of the **[Service Guide Manual](https://go.redirectingat.com/?id=92X1584492&xcust=tomshardware_7284516629806174000&xs=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fh10032.www1.hp.com%2Fctg%2FManual%2Fc04825536&sref=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.tomshardware.com%2Fthreads%2Fhp-pavilion-13-s120nr-compatible-motherboard-with-cpu-of-core-i5.3582677%2F%23post-21638342)** and on **Page 33** in the **System Board** section there is a list of it with description and spare part number. Just choose which system board and spare part number you wanted to use and look for it when you purchase.